# Is this a correct English or not?

Tags: british-english

This is a word that I want to say to my Hostel's room mate for maintaining a routine
"Don't be disturbed each other with/without our friends"

Comment: The unequivocal answer to this question is, "No, that is not correct English."  The appropriate "correct" English cannot be determined because it's very unclear what you're trying to say here.

Comment: Yes,  like this but I want to stitch on my wall,  so please write for me one more that seems to be love between me and my roommate

Comment: ‘Friends may come and go. You and I are forever.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to say something like this?

**"Let's try not to disturb each other, whether we have friends visiting or not."**

Otherwise, you would need to tell us more about your situation in order to assist you further.

Comment: Hi, and sorry (I know this is the second time today.) Please don't welcome people in your answers. It's just not part of the Stack Exchange model, which is about questions and answers, not people. It's fine in a comment, but some disagree even there. Also, please read about the purpose of [comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). If you don't know what the OP is asking, ask for a clarification in a comment. That's what they're for. Guessing on an impossible question does no one any good, including the OP.